# sql throws errors in simple querys

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jdbc

So Ive got an Java-Application which is connected to a database via JDBC. What I want to do now is get a specific entry from the database matching an input in the Java Apllication.

```
public String getA(String tablename, String input){
String result = null;
try {
    String query = ("select * from " +tablename+ " where name = "+input);
    rs = stt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()){
        String rsh = rs.getString("Name");
        result = rsh; 
    }
    } catch (Exception acc_ex){
        System.out.println("Acces excpetion in .getA: "+acc_ex);
        return null; 
    } finally {
        return result; 
    }
}
```

Throwing: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column '[input-here]' in 'where clause'`

Queries in other methods work perfectly fine, structured them the same way.
Any ideas how I can fix this? 
thanks

Comment: Do never construct your queries with concat methods.

Comment: There are so many things wrong here. Select * is very rarely a good option. You are passing in a table name as a string and then executing it. This is vulnerable to sql injection. You need to parameterize your queries. And not sure how you can't know the table name. >.<

Comment: So basically its running on a local server not connected to the internet so there is no risk of abuse or sql-injection, even if, I wouldnt care because its a simple school project so nobody would be harmed.

Comment: Do a System.out.println(query) and post it

Comment: School project I get but don't get fooled into thinking that sql injection can only happen from the internet. There is plenty of risk from employees. But as you say it is a school project. I would suggest it is still a good idea to do it righ, especially since it is still new. As I tell the kids when coaching "you play games the same way you practice". If you do it the easy way now, chances are that will continue.

Comment: Even though Im not planning on working with JDBC later (or databases) I have to agree on your opinion. When I find the time ill inform myself and may adapt it to more secure standards. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Regardless it seems Jim was able to provide you a working solution. That is the best part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string value `input` from this line of code `("select * from " +tablename+ " where name = "+input);` should have single quotes around it.

For example if your tablename is SomeTable, and your input value is SomeNameValue, the query that's sent to MySql as it's written now would be...

```
select * from SomeTable where name = SomeNameValue
```

That is wrong, it should be this, with single quotes around the value...

```
select * from SomeTable where name = 'SomeNameValue'
```

So the line of code I mentioned would be changed to this...

```
String query = ("select * from " +tablename+ " where name = '" +input+ "'");
```

Comment: The OP is asking why his query hits an exception - and not closing resources, while a valid point, is not the cause of his problem and will probably only confuse the matter.  I'd rather just answer the question than critique all the unrelated problems.

Comment: So instead of critizing you helped... was blind for such simple things and expecting a disaster.

Comment: Was just a comment (as string concatenation) , not sure this is the problem maybe he pass  for example 'Name' in input..with the quotes.. lets see...

Comment: @Zi1mann One thing to watch out for, which is one of the reasons why so many were suggesting parameterized queries, is that this breaks if `input` contains a `'`; such as if name were "O'Reilly".

Answer (score 0):

Please add single quote before and after input:

```
String query = ("select * from " + tablename + " where name = '" + input + "'");
```